# Guzzle Curl error not catche by try catch statement (Laravel)

Tags: php, laravel, curl, laravel-4

In a Laravel project I need to call API REST to delete remote data.

My problem is that my **catch statement dont catch Guzzle exception** when I got an error. My code is the following :

```
try {
    $client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
    $request = $client->delete(Config::get('REST_API').'/order-product/'.$id);
    $status = $request->getStatusCode();
} catch (Exception $e) {
    var_dump($e);exit();
}
```

The exception is catched by Laravel but not in my **catch** statement. The exception throwed by Guzzle is :

```
GuzzleHttp\Ring\Exception\ConnectException
```

It **raised in my line 3** of script and it doesn't catched in my script. Could you give me **a way to catch the Guzzle Exception** ?

I should indicate that I already seen these posts but I not get a good response : 
[How to resolve cURL Error (7): couldn't connect to host?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9922562/how-to-resolve-curl-error-7-couldnt-connect-to-host)
and
[Catching cURL errors from Guzzle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26496773/catching-curl-errors-from-guzzle)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had a similar problem and solved it using the following thing.I have used your example and given the inline comments for you to understand.

```
try {
    $client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
    $request = $client->delete(Config::get('REST_API').'/order-product/'.$id);
    $status = $request->getStatusCode();
    if($status == 200){
        $response = $response->json();

    }else{
        // The server responded with some error. You can throw back your exception
        // to the calling function or decide to handle it here

        throw new \Exception('Failed');
    }

} catch (\Guzzle\Http\Exception\ConnectException $e) {
    //Catch the guzzle connection errors over here.These errors are something 
    // like the connection failed or some other network error

    $response = json_encode((string)$e->getResponse()->getBody());
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: $response = json_encode((string)$e->getResponse()->getBody()); doesn't work for me, use: $e->gethandlerContext()['error'] grabs the error message part: e.g. 'Could not resolve host: xxxxx' and use \GuzzleHttp\Exception\ConnectException, instead of  catch (\Guzzle\Http\Exception\ConnectException $e) {

Answer (score 14):

It worked with me when I used

> \GuzzleHttp\Exception\ConnectException

instead of

> \Guzzle\Http\Exception\ConnectException

Comment: In my case, I was just missing the first backslash. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe that exception is not extending the `Exception` class. You may try to catch it like:

```
try {
    $client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
    $request = $client->delete(Config::get('REST_API').'/order-product/'.$id);
    $status = $request->getStatusCode();
} catch (\GuzzleHttp\Ring\Exception\ConnectException $e) {
    var_dump($e);exit();
} catch (Exception $e) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Sorry but I had already try this. I don't know why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

You probably mean to catch `\Exception` (in the root namespace), either by adding the backslash in the catch statement or a `use Exception` statement.

Answer (score 0):

Just Updating the answer to the new Guzzle exception namespace

```
try {
    $client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
    $request = $client->delete(Config::get('REST_API').'/order-product/'.$id);
    $status = $request->getStatusCode();
} catch (\GuzzleHttp\Exception\ConnectException $e) {
    var_dump($e);exit();
}
```